# how can i join record from different tables in jdbc

Tags: jdbc

```
    private void CoursesOfStudent () throws SQLException, IOException {
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT Students.StudentId, Students.Name, Courses.Name,Grade\n"
                + " FROM Students LEFT JOIN StudentCourses\n"
                + "ON Students.StudentId = StudentCourses.StudentId\n"
                + "LEFT JOIN Courses ON Courses.CourseId = StudentCourses.CourseId\n"
                + "WHERE Students.StudentId = ?";
        pre = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        System.out.print("Let put Id of student that you wanna list all of courses: ");
        int Stid = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        pre.setInt(1, Stid);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
         while (rs.next()) {
            Stid = rs.getInt("StudentId");
            String Stname = rs.getString("Students.Name");
            String Coname = rs.getString("Courses.Name");
            int grade = rs.getInt("Grade");

            System.out.print("StudentId: " + Stid);
            System.out.print(", StudentName: " + Stname);
            System.out.print(", CourseName: " + Coname);
            System.out.println(", Grade: " + grade);
        }
         pre.executeUpdate();
    }catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I want to join and show column in different tables in JDBC, but it got some errors, who can help me...................................................................
Thanks a lot !

This is the error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 5
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your MySQL/MySQL JDBC driver can't handle prepared statements.

Q: Are you using MySQL 5.0 or higher?

ALSO:

Make sure you've got whitespace between all your SQL statements.  Don't rely on "\n":

EXAMPLE:

```
String sql = "SELECT Students.StudentId, Students.Name, Courses.Name,Grade\n"
                + " FROM Students LEFT JOIN StudentCourses\n"
                + " ON Students.StudentId = StudentCourses.StudentId\n"
                + " LEFT JOIN Courses ON Courses.CourseId = StudentCourses.CourseId\n"
                + " WHERE Students.StudentId = ?";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use ; after ? as well. Rest depends on which driver version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong `executeQuery` method. As you are using a `PreparedStatement`, you should use the `executeQuery()` that does not take a string parameter as you are executing the statement you prepared earlier.

So use:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

The JDBC api even requires prepared statements to throw an `SQLException` if you use the [`executeQuery` that takes a string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29):

> **Throws:**
>      `SQLException` - ... , the method is called on a `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement`